# Python code to find minimum number of rows that it's sum matches specific value

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I was taking a code challenge test that needs to write a function that returns the minimum number of traffic lights used to light up number of streets.

The street number expressed as a straight line with a range from 0:n where the lights can be added at any location of n and a 2-D array called lights that represents the location of the light and it's intensity, the intensity defines the range of light (which will be right & left ) [location+intensity, Location - intensity ], ex. [3,5] light is at location 3 and can light up range from (-2 : 8 ).
We need to check the minimum lights needed to light up the full range of street and return it and if not possible then return -1

**Example**

```
n=10 , lights= [[0,5],[1,3],[5,4],[8,3]]
```

result=2 since [0,5] & [8,3] can match the condition.

**My problem**

Now I need help in how to loop on an array and find the minimum number of rows which their union to reach a specific condition[range (0,n+1), I need a loop to try a single row then if the condition not matched then try union of each 2 rows, if not matched then try union of each triple rows until the maximum limit of no. of rows in the array, if condition matched then return the minimum number of rows needed to match the condition or return -1 if condition can't be met
N.B: I need the to know how to do the loop, I can write the code but the idea of the generic equation is not coming to my mind

**Detailed Example**

```
Array =[[0,4],[0,5],[5,10],[1,9]] n=10
```

then range will be (0:11) which will be [0:10]

1. Check row (0,1,2,3) if any of them can cover the full range the return 1
2. If above not matching , check union of row [[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]], if any of them covers the full range then return 2
3. If above not matching, check the union of rows of 3 rows [[0,1,2],[0,1,3],[1,2,3]] in the array
4. If neither all conditions matched then return -1

I tried to write a code but I can't find a way how to make it simple and recursive, my way will be using for loops for 1st iteration then 2 for loops for iteration 2, then 3 loops and so on which is not efficient and not possible if Matrix dimensions are big

```py
# check if only 1 light can light up all the streets 
for i in range (arr2.shape[0]):
    for j in range (arr2.shape[1]-1):
        lights_up=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        for z in range (arr2[i][j], arr2[i][j+1]+1):
            print 'z= ',z
            lights_up[z]=1
        print ("iteration_",i,j,lights_up)  
        if lights_up==[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]:
            Min_lights=1
            print lights_up  # to be hashed
            break
    if Min_lights != -1:
        break 
    
print Min_lights
#check if 2 light can ligh up
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial approach is as follows:

**Note:** I used numpy array to hold the coverage map because, it makes slicing of a group of rows by cols easier.

```
import numpy as np
def minLights(n: int, l : list) -> int:
    # Create a street coverage map for each light
    cm = []
    for i, v in enumerate(l):
        k = [False] * n
        k[v[0]] = True
        for x in range(-v[1], v[1]+1):
            if v[0] + x >= 0 and v[0] + x < n:
                k[v[0] + x] = True                    
        cm.append(k)
    cm = np.array(cm)
    cnt = 0
    # Walk coverage map looking for a combination covering all
    while cnt < len(l):
        for row in range(len(l)):
            covered = True
            for col in range(n):
                # Testing for all False Coverage in Col
                if not cm[row:row+cnt+1, col].any():
                    covered = False 
                    break
            if covered:
                return cnt +1
        cnt += 1
    return -1
```

After performing some more extensive testing of the initial approach, I found that in cases where the optimal solution involved non-sequential lights, the approach fails to identify the best solution.  This prompted the creation of the second approach below which uses a priority queue to hold incremental solutions.  The priority weight was chosen to be the number of Uncovered street segments * the number of lights used.  This solution follows:

## Improved Solution

```
import heapq as hq

class Coverage:
    def __init__(self, n, rw, lt):
        self.n = n
        self.map = buildCoverage(self.n, lt)     
        self.includes = {rw}
        self.w = len(self.includes)*self.map.count(False)
        
    def add(self, rw, lt):
        if rw not in self.includes:
            lmap = buildCoverage(self.n, lt)
            self.merge(lmap)
            self.includes.add(rw)
            self.w = len(self.includes)* self.map.count(False)
            return self.weight
        return -1
    
    def merge(self, ltmap):
        for i in range(len(self.map)):
            if ltmap[i] or self.map[i]:
                self.map[i] = True
    
    @property
    def weight(self):
        return self.w
    
    @property
    def solution(self):
        return len(self.includes)
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.weight < other.weight
      
def buildCoverage(n, lt):
    rslt = [False]*n
    rslt[lt[0]] = True
    for x in range(-lt[1], lt[1] +1):
        if lt[0] + x >= 0 and lt[0] + x < n:
            rslt[lt[0] + x ] = True
    return rslt

def minLightsq(n: int, l : list) -> int:
    q = []
    for rw, lt in enumerate(l):
        nd = Coverage(n, rw, lt)
        #q.append((nd.weight, nd))
        hq.heappush(q,  nd)

    while len(q) > 0:
        # q = sorted(q, key= lambda x: x[0], reverse= True)
        # nd = q.pop()[1]
        nd = hq.heappop(q)
        if nd.weight == 0:
            return nd.solution
        for rw, lt in enumerate(l):
            w = nd.add(rw, lt)
            if w >= 0:
                if w == 0:
                    return len(nd.includes)
                #q.append((w, nd))
                hq.heappush(q, nd)
    return -1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts, I checked both solutions and both are giving index errors with other values, I honestly didn't understand solution no.2 since I am new to python but both are having the same issue.

**Testing input** 
[ n=8, lights= [[2,3],[8,2]]) For the previous example, The lights will be covering [2,3] --> 0:5 & [8,2] -->6:10 , Result should be -1

Comment: Actually thanks to your codes, I was able to find my need in the 1st one since I needed the 2nd part only called (    # Walk coverage map .....) but even though I am still having a problem in it since it gives 2 for the above input , I tried to debug and found that all covered is True but the requirements should also take the space between 5&6 into consideration not only 5 alone and 6 alone so if you can help in finding solution for this part would be great , Find the code in the next comment

Comment: n=8
lights= [[2,3],[8,2]]

import numpy as np
def min_Lights(n:int, lights:list ) ->int :
    ## Create 2-D list (all False) 
    list1 =[[False]*(n+1)]*len(lights)
    arr1=np.array(list1)
    # Loop to fill the illuminated range with True
    for i,v in enumerate (lights):
        if v[0]+v[1] >n :
            x=n
        else:
            x= v[0]+v[1]
        if v[0]-v[1] <0:
            y=0
        else:
            y=v[0]-v[1]
        for z in range (y,x+1):
            arr1[i][z]= True
        
    #print (arr1)
    cnt=0
<Part_1>

Comment: #  Walk coverage map looking for a combination covering all
    while cnt < len(lights):
        for row in range(len(lights)):
            covered = True
            for col in range(n):
                # Testing for all False Coverage in Col
                if not arr1 [row:row+cnt+1, col].any():
                    covered = False 
                    break
            if covered:
                return cnt +1
        cnt += 1
    return -1        

print (min_Lights(n,lights))

Comment: Can you also explain this line 
                if not arr1 [row:row+cnt+1, col].any():

Comment: I am slicing the numpy array using the [x:y, z] format.  In this format x & y reference the rows and pullout the rows beginning with x and ending with y-1, and column . So in the example I am extracting the rows beginning with row ending with row + cnt. and testing to see if any entry contains True.

Comment: Note in your test example n=8, lights = [[2,3],[8,2]], the reason you are getting index out of range is because the entry [8,2] defines a light beyond the length of the street.  The lights begin with 0 and should not exceed n-1.